# Can an official CRAN R package depend on Intel MKL and CMake? (and Check ?)

Tags: r, cmake, intel-mkl, cran

In my R package I have C code that uses [Intel MKL](https://software.intel.com/en-us/mkl) (and an open source library for [C unit testing](https://libcheck.github.io/check/)). I use [CMake](https://cmake.org/) to build the C code. I also have [Rcpp](http://www.rcpp.org/) interface code that I use to call the C code from R.

I wanted to know if [CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/) would accept this package given that you'd have to have Intel MKL and CMake already installed on your system for it to work?

I'm not too worried about the unit testing, I can always get rid of that, but I definitely need Intel MKL because I'm using linear algebra routines that are specific to MKL e.g. Sparse-Matrix-Dense-Matrix multiply etc.

The reason I need CMake is because currently, that's what I'm using to build a static library from the C code and manipulate the `Makevars` file in the package's `src` folder, so that I can link the Rcpp interface code against the C library.

My `Makevars` looks as follows:

```
PKG_CPPFLAGS=-I/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include -I/opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2019.4.243/linux/mkl/include -I./C
PKG_LIBS=-L./C/cmake-build-release -lbcd -llog -Wl,--start-group /opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2019.4.243/linux/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_intel_ilp64.a /opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2019.4.243/linux/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_sequential.a /opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2019.4.243/linux/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_core.a -Wl,--end-group -lpthread -lm -ldl
```

This works on Ubuntu, but I'm worried about OS X and especially Windows. For example, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10723165/using-visual-c-with-r/44381109#44381109) someone claims that Intel MKL is not compatible with `minGW`.

I know that there are many CRAN packages that use either MKL or CMake. But for the ones that I've investiaged, MKL is used as an optional BLAS library and CMake is used to build what's under the `inst` folder, which did not depend on external libraries. I've looked at [writing R extensions](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html) and also the [CRAN submission page](https://cran.r-project.org/) but wasn't able to find find an answer. I thought that since there are more and more people interested in using CMake and MKL with R it would be good to have a SO post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are tieing this up from the wrong end.

You have a more narrow and specialised solution you created (MKL, CMake).

Now you are worried that it may be too specialised. You are on the right path. First off, CMake *is* used by other packages so you could just declare it as a `SystemRequirements:`.  Second, MKL is tougher but ... also truly specialised.

Methinks the general recommendation *for a broader CRAN upload* would be to

- relax your code requirements: use MKL if present, but offer a fallback when not; now you no longer require MKL
- ditto for CMake: keep it and depend on it, better still try to not require it as most 15000 other CRAN package no not need it either.

Once you hit these two you're ready for a CRAN upload. If all this seems to onerous, just stick with a GitHub repository or maybe a [drat](https://cloud.r-project.org/web/packages/drat/readme/README.html) repo.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. It will take some time but it's possible to remove the dependencies. However, it would come at a performance cost. Currently, I'm heavily using the fact that MKL can do operations with sparse and dense objects. Also I was planning to extend the package to be able to work with sparse matrices only, with MKL I would not need an additional BLAS. I know that Matrix uses suiteSparse for sprase objects, but I wasn't able to figure out how it does a dense-sparse matrix-matrix multiply. Does it convert sparse mtx to dense? Thanks!

Comment: I thin suiteSparse, as a dedicated library, has specialised algorithms. As does for example Armadillo (which we make accessible via RcppArmadillo).